# save-pixels leading to corrupted and desaturated images on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using save-pixels and get-pixels npm modules to get an ndarray from a DataURL and save pixels to convert an image ndarray to a DataURL. But I am facing a few issues while using save-image to make a DataURL. Am I doing this correctly? Is there a better way to do this?

This is the code I am using:

```
var buffer = require('fs').createWriteStream('output.txt');
var enc = require('base64-stream').encode();
savePixels(pixels, 'png').on('end', function() {
    //Writes a DataURL to  output.txt
    buffer.write("data:image/png;base64,"+enc.read().toString());
}).pipe(enc);
```

Issues I Get : The image becomes desaturated and DataURL of PNG Images is incomplete.

For complete reference:
http://github.com/publiclab/image-sequencer/issues/25

Comment: Also a great, well-organized set of examples of this happening, with before/after images, here: https://github.com/scijs/save-pixels/issues/22

Comment: I did post one just now! Good idea: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/46330420-images-getting-desaturated-on-node-js-datauri-corrupted-at-times

Comment: Thanks for the link, @jywarren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback should be on the piping and not the savePixels. That was leading to incomplete images.
So the code should be this:

```
var buffer = require('fs').createWriteStream('output.txt');
var enc = require('base64-stream').encode();
savePixels(pixels, 'png').pipe(enc).on('end', function() {
    //Writes a DataURL to  output.txt
    buffer.write("data:image/png;base64,"+enc.read().toString());
});
```